# How can I pick a color from a ColorMap and colorize selected image pixels with this color

Tags: image-processing, color

I have a binarized image and would like to set pixel values which are 1 to a certain (any) color picked from `ColorData["TemperatureMap"]` and 0 to another color of `"TemperatureMap"`.

How can I do that?

[image: my image]

Thanks in advance.
Milenko

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Using `EventHandler` and `TemperatureMap`:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmKND.png"];

DynamicModule[{col = Green}, 
 EventHandler[Column[{ColorData["TemperatureMap", "Image"], 
    Dynamic@Colorize[image, ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> col}, ImageSize -> 300]}], 
    {"MouseClicked" :> 
     (col = ColorData["TemperatureMap"][First[MousePosition["Graphics"]]])}, 
  PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True]]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Select background color using right-mouse-click:

```
DynamicModule[{col1 = Green, col2 = White}, 
 EventHandler[Column[{ColorData["TemperatureMap", "Image"], 
    Dynamic@Colorize[image, ColorRules -> {0 -> col2, 1 -> col1},ImageSize -> 300]}], 
 {{"MouseClicked", 1} :> 
  (col1 = ColorData["TemperatureMap"][First[MousePosition["Graphics"]]]),
  {"MouseClicked", 2} :> 
  (col2 = ColorData["TemperatureMap"][First[MousePosition["Graphics"]]])}, 
   PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True]]
```

[image]

**Update 3:**

> *I want to pick up a special color from the color table "without GUI" and set all intensities of 1 with this color ...*

```
col1 = ColorData["SunsetColors"][.7];
col2 = ColorData["SunsetColors"][.1]; 
Colorize[image,  ColorRules -> {0 -> col2, 1 -> col1}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmKND.png"];
Column[{ColorSetter[Dynamic[x]], 
      Dynamic@Colorize[MorphologicalComponents@image, ColorRules -> {0 -> White, _ :> x}]}]
```

[image]

Clicking on the `ColorSetter` button invokes color selection dialog:

[image]

After selecting a color, the colors in the image are updated:

[image]

Comment: This is great ;-)

But how is it if I wish to select a special color from the color table with GUI interaction.
For example each color should represent a certain depth information of the 2d image and I want to do that automatically.

Comment: @MilenkoRubin-Zuzic, this sounds like a good candidate for a new question.

Comment: Dear kguler, 
I meant: I want to pick up a special color from the color table "without GUI" and set all intensities of 1 with this color ... is that possible?

Comment: @Milenko, something like `col1 = ColorData["TemperatureMap"][.2]; 
col2 = ColorData["TemperatureMap"][.6];
Colorize[image, ColorRules -> {0 -> col2, 1 -> col1}, 
 ImageSize -> 300]`?

Comment: Great ... thanks a lot